# Get Max id mongodb in Pentaho spoon

Tags: pentaho-spoon

I want to get the maximum id in mongodb using PDI spoon.

I have this fields in my collection:

- Id  String
- Genre String

Before I insert new record I should get the maximum Id.

Can you help me on how to get the maximum Id?

Comment: related
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415921/lookup-values-in-mongodb-pentaho-spoon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MongoDB Input step.

Use the following query:

({
    $group: {
        _id: '',
        theMaxId: {
            $max: "$_id"
        }
    }
}

Note:  This is an aggregation framework query and you must check the "Query is aggregation pipeline" box at the bottom of the query box on the query tab.

As a side note - if you are using the MongoDB id's, it is auto-incrementing so you don't need to find the max, increment it and use if for your new record.

Hope that helps,

Mark